# What's the most efficient way to get notified when a new node with certain attribute was added?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Example:

```
<div my-custom-attr></div>
```

I wanna end up with a handler that upon DOM modification, provides all the elements with that custom attribute:

```
function onCustomAttrElementAdd(elements: HtmlElement[]): void {

...

}
```

I investigated `MutationObserver`, but couldn't figure out a way to only fire off the nodes with the custom attribute. It seems that it always provides the whole dom subtree that got appended. Filtering them out to find the elements with the custom attribute is not an option for me. It causes an unacceptable resources hit.

Can you think of any other api/approach?

Comment: If it's third party code that modifies attribute MutationObserver is probably best route. If it's your code that changes them,  choices are more robust

Comment: @charlietfl It's my code. Please proceed